# Angular Material MatDialog Not work for Angular-6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm beginner for the Angular/Angular material and I tried to used [`MatDialog`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

I followed the that instruction , but is it not work for me [MatDialog-Overview](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Any One know how to use correctly `MatDialog` ?

[stackblitz code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxh2vi)

My code

```
   <!--Add new button-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse bd-highlight">
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><button mat-flat-button class="btn-sg"  color="primary"  style=" width:200px; color: white " (click)="openDialog()" >+ Add New</button></div>
    </div>
    <!--/ End Add new button-->
```

**.ts**

```
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';


 openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you import the required modules? What is the error that you're getting? Please create a stackblitz if possible.

Comment: Yes Sir, ok will update  stackblitz  live code part

Comment: Hello core114 i see you already got an answer to your question anyway let me tell you that its a good practice to use the Angular CLI to generate the basic code to you  like components , services and so one. Like this you keep your code clean , maintainable and you will not miss the basic structure or your  (pipes , directives , components , services ) !

Comment: @TiagoNeiva Hello sir, I'm still beginner for the Angular ,can you please provide correctly that one .

Comment: Hello on your Angular console if you make this command: `ng g c nameOfComponent` Angular will generate the files for you. ng  g ( means generate ) C , means component. You can also make `ng g s nameOfService` . After this you only need to import what you need and make your code :)

Comment: @TiagoNeiva Sir, I understood.Thanks for your valuable guidance

Comment: No problem i hope it could be useful for you! Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your stackblitz is missing a dialog component class.

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'Dialogpge',
  templateUrl: 'Dialogpge.html',
})
export class Dialogpge {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

have this and import this in the main.ts and dialog-overview-example.ts file.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxh2vi-unhrrq) (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxh2vi-unhrrq)  is the working version of stackblitz forked from your version